# Making a c# program go back to a point and carry on

Tags: c#, performance, methods

I have a list of code that is implemented from a button click load event in one method. I also have a Mouse Event that returns the e.X and e.Y values. MY problem is that the program runs through the button click load event and I can see the mouse events but I do not know how to return the program to run it again from a position with the new e.X and e.Y values. I have tried to separate it into various methods but I cannot seem to be able to 'call' them or 'goto' them. Any advice on what I need to do? The code is listed below.

Many thanks Steve

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace HPXSV8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int curX;
        private int curY;
        //private double ll;
        //private double lr;
        //private double lt;
        //private double lb;
        //private double GPSLat;
        //private double GPSLong;
        public int allimages;

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void btnLoadFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Loads the data file syvwname

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Load Survey View Data File";
            ofd.Filter = "Survey View File |*.syvw";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string syvwname = ofd.FileName;
                string sfn = ofd.SafeFileName;
                string[] loaddata = new string[500];
                int allimages = 0;
                string line;

                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(syvwname);
                List<string> list = new List<string>();

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
                    loaddata[allimages] = line;
                    allimages++;
                }

                string[,] gpsdata = new string[allimages, 3];
                int z = 0;

                do
                {

                    //slices up the .syvw file into 3 string values comma delimited
                    string chop1 = loaddata[z];

                    string[] part = chop1.Split(',');
                    string[] parts = part.ToArray();
                    gpsdata[z, 0] = parts[0];
                    gpsdata[z, 1] = parts[1];
                    gpsdata[z, 2] = parts[2];
                    z++;

                }
                while (z < allimages);

                //load jpg 0001 to picture box
                int strlength = syvwname.Length;
                int sfnamelength = sfn.Length;
                string mainimage = gpsdata[0, 0];
                string trimname = syvwname.Remove(strlength - sfnamelength, sfnamelength);
                string filelocation = (trimname + @"\" + mainimage);
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = filelocation;



                //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$



                //Calculate values of lat and long to compare with image values

                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                double picboxX = 800.00; ////check these values in final program size

                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

                //Calculate fraction position of cursor to picture

                double curposX = curX / picboxX;

                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                label1.Text = "CurposX = " + curposX.ToString();
                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


                //Calculate values of lat and long to compare with image values

                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%          
                double picboxY = 600.00;
                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

                //Calculate fraction position of cursor to picture           
                double curposY = curY / picboxY;
                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                label2.Text = "CurposY =" + curposY.ToString(); // Test Line
                                                                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

                /// Calculate GPSLongditude from mouse positions

                double ll = Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[2, 1]); //??????????????????????????????
                double lr = Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[2, 2]);
                //GPS Postion calculations based on picture box mouse position

                //Longitude
                double GPSLong = ll + ((lr - ll) * curposX);

                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                label3.Text = "GpsLong =" + GPSLong.ToString(); /// Test Line
                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


                // Calculate GPSLatitude from mouse positions

                double lb = Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[1, 2]);
                double lt = Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[1, 1]);

                //GPS Postion calculations based on picture box mouse position

                //Latitude
                double GPSLat = lt + ((lb - lt) * curposY);


                //Look for values in my_datatable that fall within +/- 0.0005 of GPS Lat and Long
                // This may be made to be a variable to increase the number of images
                //=================================================================================
                //Look for values in gpsdata[]

                int row = 3;
                int chs = 0;
                string[] chosenimage = new string[allimages]; // value if all images are selected

                //=================================================================================
                double area = 0.0005; //later make this a UI variable
                                      //=================================================================================
                do
                {
                    //make 4 values +/- 0.0005 of gpsdata[]

                    if (GPSLat <= (Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[row, 1]) + area))
                    {
                        if (GPSLat >= (Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[row, 1]) - area))
                        {
                            if (GPSLong <= (Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[row, 2]) + area))
                            {
                                if (GPSLong >= (Convert.ToDouble(gpsdata[row, 2]) - area))
                                {
                                    chosenimage[chs] = gpsdata[row, 0];
                                    chs++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    row++;
                }
                while (row < allimages);
                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                label4.Text = "GpsLat = " + GPSLat.ToString();
                //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(line);
                    chosenimage[chs] = line;
                    allimages++;
                }
            }
        }


        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        public void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Use to select images to use for notes
            //label1.Text = insertnote.Text;
        }

        public void insertnote_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Use for entering text into notepad area

        }

        public void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        { 
        //Get location of mouse click on 001.jpg

            int curX = e.X;
            int curY = e.Y;
            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            label1.Text = "X = " + curY.ToString() + " ;  Y =" + curY.ToString(); /// Test Line
            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++         



        }

    }

} // End of Namespace HPXSV8
```

Comment: Does `btnLoadFiles_Click` run to completion before new mouse event?

Comment: int curX = e.X; - you are not writing to your private field, but new variable, change it to curX = e.X;

Comment: @Andrii Yes, but when I have made another method say from //$$$$$$$$$$$ It ignores the new method a goes straight to the mouse event...

Comment: @Antonin - just changed that, but still no joy...

Comment: I still have hard time to understand what is the current problem and what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to extract a method? Maybe you can give an example of expected behavior?

Comment: @Andrii What I want it to do is

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please be more specific. Reduce the code example to a good [mcve]. State clearly and precisely what that code example does now, and what you want it to do instead. See also [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. Make sure you pay attention also to the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question. You have two events. You want Event A to update the X and Y values and the other Event B to do some calculation based on those values. If Event A occurs during the calculation, you want to redo the calculation.

I'll have to check up on this later, but I'm sure that the events you wrote are blocking. Meaning Event A has to complete before it can proceed with Event B. Additionally, Event B has to complete before it can proceed with Event A. This is why it won't work.

You could try doing this with a worker thread. Event B signals the thread to perform calculations. Event A will tell the worker thread that a value is invalid and has to redo a calculation.

Comment: Just like the OP you could do with a few of those line breaks that come free when pressing the EnterKey..

Comment: @Informat I shall give the background worker method a try ... :)

Comment: @Informant I have added the code to handle the Background worker to (private void backgroundWorker_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) The problem is that I need to access the gpsdata[,] array. How can I do that from within the backgroundWorker_DoWork method?

Comment: You should be able to pass a reference of that array to your background worker in the DoWorkEventArgs parameter.